# Spring Boot Component Scan

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing a new spring boot project where my root package name is **"com.example"**. In my gradle configuration, I am adding a dependency of a third party library, which has root package name as **"org.base"**. Now, this library has classes with @Component annotation which I want to use in my code leveraging @Autowired

In my Config class I am scanning base package of third party library as well.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"org.base", "com.example"})
public class ServiceConfig{...}
```

When I run the application, spring is not able to find/create beans from this library and I am getting a bean not found error.

For Component Scan to work, does the root package have to be same?

Error Details: UserService required a bean of type 'org.base.util.CommonUtils' that could not be found.

UserService is my service

Comment: Can you post the error details ?

Comment: Is your `ServiceConfig` class being picked up by component scanning (or is it declared explicitly)? For instance, does it have a `@Configuration` annotation? Otherwise, the `ServiceConfig` bean might not even be picked up by component scanning.

Comment: Yes and other beans in my Service Config class are getting instantiated

Comment: Is the external JAR available in the classpath, for instance by declaring it as a dependency in the pom.xml?

Comment: Every class to be autowired should be annotated with Bean,Component,Service,Respository. In case of third party classes, there may not be any annotations. So you have to use without autowiring. Others can review my points.

Comment: A third-party library that requires you to component scan it is a bit unpleasant. Are you sure that's necessary? In a Spring Boot context, auto-configuration would more common. for Spring in general an `@Enable…` annotation is preferred to having to component scan third-party code.

Comment: Andy Sir, can we directly use any third party class (which is inside a jar file) using autowiring ? I mean normally we provide annotations in the class what we write for autowiring. Can we use any class from apache-commons by autowiring in spring ?

Comment: why not `ComponentScan` on main class instead of `ServiceConfig` class

Answer (score 0):

`@ComponentScan` will only work if the classes are annotated with spring annotations like `@Component` or `@Service` etc. How you can fix this is to use declarative approach, use `@Bean` to class which annotated with `@Configuration` will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not having proper annotations. I finally fixed this as below

```
@Component
public Class UserService {
    @Autowired
    @Lazy
    private CommonUtils commonUtils;
}
```

I had to use @Lazy annotations for dependencies from third party Library. During eager initialization, spring was not able to find the dependency bean.